# Python to access Salesforce MFA in simple-salesforce

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce-lightning, simple-salesforce

I am currently using the simple-salesforce package in python to retrieve report from Salesforce. But im getting below error msg:

> SalesforceAuthenticationFailed  SalesforceAuthenticationFailed:
> INVALID_SSO_GATEWAY_URL: the single sign on gateway url for the org is
> invalid

below is my code which i used in python to access Salesforce(with multi factor Authenticator enabled)

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce

sf = Salesforce(username='orgmailid@example.com', password='password', security_token='token')
```

which is not working, Any help will be appreciated. Could anyone please let me kow how to access salesforce with MFA enabled and when i run my python code, it should ask for multi factor authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple-salesforce package, to my knowledge, does not natively support MFA in the way you're hoping. You can look this up https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/334782

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i need to code in python in such a way i should enter username , password, security token of salesforce in program and since salesforce has multi factor authentication enabled, it should prompt me to enter the code from MFA and i shld enter code then my program shld run and produce desired results. is there ay way for that. please help